# Calendar built with Tex and TikZ

Tags: pdftex, tikz-calendar

I'd like to make a kind of "ppt like" planning with several lines of project and a timeline of a few weeks.
The closest result I managed to build (with the help of chatGPT) is this:
[image]

But there's a lot of defaults, do you know if this exists as template? I used tikz and not pgfgantt cause I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks for reading this and good day to all :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{project1color}{RGB}{61,153,112}
\definecolor{project2color}{RGB}{231,76,60}
\definecolor{project3color}{RGB}{65,131,215}

\newcommand{\drawBar}[4]{ % Usage : \drawBar{X coord}{Y coord}{p1}{p 2}{p 3}

\fill[#3] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+#4/3,#2+0.3);
\fill[#3!50!white] (#1+#4/3,#2) rectangle (#1+#4*2/3,#2+0.3);
\fill[#3!80!white] (#1+#4*2/3,#2) rectangle (#1+#4,#2+0.3);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]

% projects
\draw (-0.5,-1) -- (-0.5,3) node[above,midway,rotate=90] {project 1};
\draw (-0.5,4) -- (-0.5,8) node[above,midway,rotate=90] {project 2};
\draw (-0.5,9) -- (-0.5,13) node[above,midway,rotate=90] {project 3};

% Planning
\drawBar{0}{2}{project1color}{30}
\drawBar{0}{6}{project2color}{45}
\drawBar{0}{10}{project3color}{20}

% Dates

\foreach \w in {1,...,18} {
\node[anchor=north,rotate=45] at (\w*7-3.5,0) {\w};
\foreach \d/\j in {1/0,2/1,3/2} {
\node[anchor=north] at (\w*7-3+\j,-1) {};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Which code did the Artificial Incompetence show you? Please post it, ... or doesn't it compile? // I suggest to spend a little more time on https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines for more NI (Natural Intelligence ;-) )

Comment: Using GitHub Copilot to assist Tik*Z drawing is quite pleasant (helps us do trivial & repetitive things), but the first step is to know what to draw as MS-SPO said :-)   It is like art creation.

Comment: You did check this section, didn’t you? https://tikz.dev/library-calender

Comment: pgfgantt is actually quite simple in my experience, and the result surely looks nicer than what you have now :)

Comment: I have to say, development is not quite my goal here. I was looking for a quick/lazy solution to my problem: generating simply a planning without struggling with the automatic layout. Since most of the code I use is produced by chatGPT, and I have to say I'm impressed by its quality (not being a dev though, difficult maybe for me to judge), I gave a try for a latex doc. You'd be surprised but must of the code been produced flawlessly within a few secs... Will have a look to your links but was really looking for a ready to fly template, again: shame on me but I'm a lazy one :)

Comment: Please. Copy. Your. Code. As it‘s now this question adds little value to this community and is very unspecific wrt what exactly you want to visualize.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, which has some potential problems built-in. // However, at the moment you post 3 questions as far as I can see: 1) something about defaults, 2) something about a template, 3) simplifying? // This usually leads to a close-vote, as 1 question should address exactly 1 problem, so each answer can be 1 specific solution. // So I suggest to sharpen your focus, i.e. make 1 and only 1 question crystalclear, while deleting the others. Thank you // P.S.: It might be a good idea to talk a little about the way you want to use it, too.

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed your answer. If I can keep only one that would be a template. I'm trying to build a multiline calendar from now to end of august, with 3 sections each time: tst, uat and prod. I'm project manager for IT, I have a bunch of apps who I need to upgrade the platform, and want something less painful than powerpoint, which I'm pretty reluctant to use. I don't have much time to spend on it unfortunately, reason why I chatgpted it and now looking for a template. Not a first world problem though, if I've been a bit naive trying latex without any knowledge, ppt will do just fine.

Comment: Hi, @Marijn, gave pgfgantt a try, turns out to be a not so pretty but very handy solution. I think I'll stick to it thanks for your help!